# pandas.DataFrame / when is it better not to use itterows()?

Tags: python, pandas, image, loops

It makes sense to me to use iterrows() sparingly ( https://statisticsglobe.com/iterate-through-rows-pandas-dataframe-python ), however I find myself needing to use it frequently.

Example:

- I've been storing metadata for images in a DataFrame
- I'm tempted to store the images too (is that foolish b/c it is inefficient?)

To load images and store them in a DataFrame, I could find some `pythonic` way to write elegant code, but in reality it is the loading of the image that takes all the time.  Who cares if iterrows() is not efficient, eliminating it won't really speed up the code... or will it?

Context:

- The application of this code is for 10's of images, not 1000's of images
- I use the DataFrames as a way to associate data, sort, search.  I could use lists of unique classes, but is that really more efficient?  Easier to read?  Easier to debug?

Comment: What's the question? Seems to me that you're thinking out loud but haven't got a proper question formulated.

Comment: 10's of images' metadata and thinking of storing images too? It sounds like this should not be a DataFrame but a list of dataclass instances or something else.

Comment: For wherever you're using `iterrows()`, you can probably just be using `apply(func, axis=1)` Which still isn't great, but it's better than manually looping.